# Comprehensive Assessment Test for Undergraduate Math Program

Tags: undergraduate-education, test-design

My department uses the Major Field Assessment Test in Math (I think we refer to it as the "MFT") and that is great for its purpose. However, I am currently teaching a capstone course where we spend about half the semester working through multiple choice Math GRE-type questions which run the spectrum of undergraduate math; calculus I, II and III, differential equations, linear algebra, complex analysis, real analysis, elementary topology, basic abstract algebra and some combinatorics. I'd like to give a 2 hour final which is roughly reflective of these topics and of course I can just recycle the multiple choice questions I have at my disposal. But, I'd rather use a short-answer test which runs through a similar range of topics. Hence my question:

> Do you know of a broad spectrum math test at the undergraduate level which is suitable for Math majors who have completed real and abstract algebra ? Either multiple choice or short-answer will be useful for my purpose.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Comprehensive, 2 hour, multiple choice and short answer don't get along very well.

Comment: no test is perfect, but, I want to do the most I can with the time. In any event, this question is hypothetical at this point since I already gave a test for this class.